# AssociationProxy with eager loading and AsyncSession

Tags: sqlalchemy

How configure eager loading for association proxy using AsyncSession?

I have M2M relationship with AssociationProxy:

```
class Twit(Base):
    tweet_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    creator=lambda media: MediaTwit(media=media),
    )
    like: Mapped[list['Like']] = relationship(
        back_populates='twit', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='selectin'
    )
    likes: AssociationProxy[list['User']] = association_proxy(
        'like', 'user', creator=lambda user: Like(user=user)
    )

class Like(Base):
    twit_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('twit.tweet_id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True, index=True
    )
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True, index=True
    )
    twit: Mapped[Twit] = relationship(back_populates='like')
    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship()

class User(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    key: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64))
```

I tried options:

```
query = select(Twit).filter_by(tweet_id=1).options(selectinload(Twit.likes))
res = await db.execute(query)
```

But it did not work:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: expected ORM mapped attribute for loader strategy argument
```

Comment: have you figured it out, what was the error ?